# SwiftUI Contentview click are taking multiple attempts to happen

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nsmenuitem

Iam working on MacOS Application, My entire code is written in Swift but for adding MenuItem I preferred to use SwiftUI ContentView. To do that I have written following code.

```
class StatusBarController {
    
    var statusBar: NSStatusBar!
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem!
    var nsMenu = NSMenu()
    
    init(delegate: AppDelegate) {
        
        statusBar = NSStatusBar()
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.squareLength)

        statusItem.button?.image = NSImage(systemSymbolName: "star.fill", accessibilityDescription: "Status bar icon")

        let menuItem = NSMenuItem()
        let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        
        controller.view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 320)
        menuItem.view = controller.view
        
        
        nsMenu.addItem(menuItem)
        statusItem.menu = nsMenu
    }
}
```

This is working fine Im able to present ContentView successfully but in ContentView there is click action added on label. But it's taking multiple attempts(3-4) to just do single click. I did lot of research it seems issue of windows hierarchy. May be Contentview window is not in front and hence click is not passing through properly.What should I do here so that click will happen immediately in single click.

This is my content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
           
         
            HStack() {
                Text("Quit")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle()).onTapGesture {
              
                //This is the action Im talking about
                NSApp.terminate(self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? You mention a click action on label but don't show any of that code

Comment: Can you provide the macOS version you're on? The code works fine for me.

Comment: Ventura 13.5 Basically for me quit action happen but not in first click it takes 3-4 attempts.